# OpenCL Kernel won't work until another buffer creation call

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a OpenCL buffer that is created via:

```
return cl::Buffer(_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, size);
```

I write data to that buffer and want to use it later in a kernel.
I get a strange behavior thought because my kernel wont work with that buffer. Only when I randomly call

```
BufferContainer blah(oclEnvironment, cv::Size(width, height), 3);
```

calls the above function to create a same sized buffer again, the kernel works. I don't call blah.Write(...) at all. It seems to work with the data I wrote to the first buffer. But if I comment out that single line with the "blah" buffer it wont work again.

e: both buffers are created with the exact same dimensions.

e2: does it have something to do with the command queue and the order of objects there?

Basically I try to run a kernel to reduce the image and find the max hsv v value. Then after that kernel finishes and gives me the max I run the next kernel with one parameter set to that found maximum. So the call chain is like:

```
float maxV = _maxValueReduce->GetValueMaximum(oclEnvironment, fiBuffer, width, height, true);

//starting to paramter the next kernel
...
_kernel.setArg(8, maxV);
oclEnvironment._commandQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(_kernel, cl::NullRange, global, local);
```

And the GetValueMaximum(...) starts itself a reducing kernel to find that maximum.

e3:

```
float OclMaxValueReduce::GetValueMaximum(OclEnvironment& oclEnvironment, 
BufferContainer& source, int width, int height, const bool sync)
{
//Create the result buffer
//Intel HD 530 can have a max. workgroup size of 256.
int dim1 = 16;
int dim2 = 16;
cl::NDRange local(dim1, dim2,1);
cl::NDRange global(source._size.width, source._size.height, 1);


//Calculate the number of workgroups
int numberOfWorkgroups = ceil((width * height) / (float)(dim1 * dim2));

//each workgroup reduces the data to a single element. This elements are then reduced on host in the final reduction step.
//First create the buffer for the workgroups result
BufferContainer result(oclEnvironment, cv::Size(numberOfWorkgroups, 1), sizeof(float));

//set the kernel arguments
_kernel.setArg(0, source.GetOclBuffer());
_kernel.setArg(1, result.GetOclBuffer());
_kernel.setArg(2, width);
_kernel.setArg(3, height);


oclEnvironment._commandQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(_kernel, cl::NullRange, global, local);

if (sync)
    oclEnvironment._commandQueue.finish();

//retrieve the reduced result array. The final reduce step is done here on host.

float* dest = new float[numberOfWorkgroups];
ReadBuffer(oclEnvironment, result.GetOclBuffer(), dest, numberOfWorkgroups);

std::vector<float> resultArray(dest, dest + numberOfWorkgroups);
delete[] dest;

//find and return the max in array.
std::vector<float>::iterator it;
it = std::max_element(resultArray.begin(), resultArray.end());

return resultArray[std::distance(resultArray.begin(), it)];


}
```

and this calls the read buffer:

```
/* Read a float array from ocl buffer*/
void OclMaxValueReduce::ReadBuffer(OclEnvironment oclEnvironment, cl::Buffer 
&resultBuffer, float* dest, const size_t size) {
int errcode;
float* resultData = (float*)oclEnvironment._commandQueue.enqueueMapBuffer(resultBuffer, true, CL_MAP_READ, 0, size * sizeof(float), 0, 0, &errcode);



if (errcode)
    throw std::exception(std::string("OclEnvironment::ReadBuffer: OCL could not map Buffer!").data(), errcode);

//std::copy(resultData, (resultData + size), dest);
memcpy(dest, resultData, size * sizeof(float));

cl::Event testEvent;

oclEnvironment._commandQueue.enqueueUnmapMemObject(resultBuffer, resultData, NULL, &testEvent); // Unmap Buffer

testEvent.wait();
}
```

Comment: Is your write to the buffer async or synchronous, and is your command queue out of order or not? Ideally, show all OpenCL calls in sequence that are necessary as a minimum repro. Also, please define "won't work". Crashes? Returns an error? Incorrect calculation result? If the latter, how are you retrieving the result?

Comment: I tried both, creating the command queue with out of order flag and with no flag, makes no difference. I don't know if the write is aync, how do I tell that? I call enqueueMapBuffer(..., CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION, ...) and copy my data to that pointer. Unmap it afterwards.
Won't work is that the reduce kernel gives back valid maxima if it works and some very low values near zero when it won't work. So I think the data of the buffer might be different in both cases. No error. Just the maxV variable is very low instead of a true found maximum in the fine case.

Comment: Ah, you're using the memory-mapping API. This too can be async, if you specify [`blocking_map`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html) as true. The [unmapping](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueUnmapMemObject.html) can also take time to complete, so you should probably make the start of the kernel depend on the completion event from unmapping. But as you haven't provided the code I can only guess. (And again, have you ruled out that your problem isn't with getting your result out?)

Comment: Okay I tried it with a event in enqueueunmapObject call and called event.wait() afterwards. still did not change it. I will edit the question and add further code so you can see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `BufferContainer` doesn't seem to be part of the standard C++ wrapper for OpenCL, and you haven't posted its code. Could it be the problem lies in its implementation? I can't see anything obvious that's wrong in the code you've posted. (although your ReadBuffer implementation seems unnecessarily complex and potentially slow - you just `memcpy` the mapped pointer, so why not use `enqueueReadBuffer()`?) At the same time you haven't posted anywhere near enough code to reproduce the issue, so there's a high chance the problem is in some code you haven't posted.